# Find a word in a line based on next word

Tags: java, cobol

I have a file and here is a portion of of the file. The common word in all lines is PIC here and I am able to find out the index of PIC.  I am trying to extract the description for each line. Here how can I extract the word before the word PIC?

```
          15 EXTR-SITE                                 PIC X.
        05 EXTR-DBA                                    PIC X.
TE0305*     05 EXTR-BRANCH                         PIC X(05).
TE0305*     05 EXTR-NUMBER                         PIC X(06).
TE0305      05 FILLER                                  PIC X(11).
CW0104        10 EXTR-TEXT6                       PIC X(67).
CW0104        10 EXTR-TEXT7                       PIC X(67).
CW0104*     05 FILLER                                  PIC X(567).
```

I have to get result like below

```
EXTR-SITE 
EXTR-DBA
EXTR-NUMBER
-------
FILLER
```

Is there any expression I can use to find the word before 'PIC'?

Here is my code to get lines that contain 'PIC':

```
int wordStartIndex = line.indexOf("PIC");
int wordEndIndex = line.indexOf(".");
if ((wordStartIndex > -1) && (wordEndIndex >= wordStartIndex)) {
System.out.println(line); }
```

Comment: try using the String.split function

Comment: Just to add warnings.  If you are attempting to parse COBOL, be wary of `PIC` as alias of `PICTURE`, and watch for fields names that may contain PIC anywhere in the name.  Maybe worry about weeding out comment lines as well, `*` in column 7, (or 1 for some free form compilers, but that extension's support can lead to ambiguous code parsing, so boo hiss on its use), and highly recommended `*>`, skip to end of line comment markers.

Comment: To add to Brian's warnings: there is no requirement that the name of the item is on the same line as the PIC/PICTURE;  there is no requirement that an item has a PIC/PICTURE; there is no requirement that an item has a name; there is no requirement that a name is the data immediately before a PIC/PICTURE. The sample you show would not even compile, the `FILLER` after EXTR-NUMBER should not have a PIC/PICTURE.

Comment: What is the compiler and OS that you are getting this COBOL code from? Are you getting entire programs?

Comment: Sorry @BillWoodger, but in the description of the question he is saying _I am trying to extract description for each line_.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin yes, and as long as their data only looks like that it'll be OK. The thing is, that is quite unlikely.  The code sample shown won't even compile, and if non-compilable code is OK for input, then no-one stands a chance :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger I understand that you're looking at the question from a cobol point of view. You're right. But from a Java point of view, our answers respond to the requirements expressed in the question, don't you think?

Comment: @kods An entirely routine data-definition would be `03  EXTR-COUNT COMP-3 PIC 9(5).` Also valid `05  EXTR-NAME-ADDR.` Also `05  PIC X`. Also `05`. I think you should thank the answerers with a a vote each, and ask a new question once you understand the data, or a new question on how to understand the data.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin Yes, I think the question is pickled. The answers will even be useful once the data is understood, but the question needs re-writing. So rather than mess this one, I'm going to try to close it to get another asked. I'm surprised Java doesn't have a "word" function, but I know zip about Java. Sorry about that.

Comment: @kods to extend on Brian's points, EXTE-EPIC could be a name, there are people who write PICTURE in full. Old code is often commented out. Comments can refer to data-items giving you false hits.

Comment: @BillWoodger - Yes, my error.  I was conflating USAGE and PICTURE.

Comment: You might be better off parsing for the levels, hint : in a similar way to a compiler.  Check out the Gnu Cobol / Open Cobol project.  Essentially building a tree of containers.  It's all about what the scope terminators might be.  You are not the first person to do this. The redefines (like a UNION), the switches/enumeration - level 77 etc. all need to be considered.

Comment: If this is pure source code, fair enough too, but MAP and CROSS REFERENCE switches provide data dictionary fodder on serious platforms such as OpenVMS and z/OS.

Comment: The Java-oriented comments (and answers) certainly address the Java coding issues - however - this is about parsing COBOL data definitions and the question itself is flawed. The OP should refer to a COBOL language reference if the desire is to construct a general purpose solution. If the desire is for a site (or file) specific solution, by all means try to do this with regexes and other string manipulations. @BillWoodger's answer deals with many more of the COBOL coding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "15 EXTR-SITE                                 PIC X.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(.*?\\s+)+(.*?)(?=\\s+PIC).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P:

```
EXTR-SITE
```

Explanation :

```
(.*?\\s+)+(.*?)(?=\\s+PIC).*", "$1") :

(.*?\\s+)+ --> Find one or more groups of "anything" which is followed by a space.

(.*?)(?=\\s+PIC) -->find a group of "any set of characters" which are followed by a space and the word "PIC".
.* --> Select everything after PIC.

$1 --> the contents of the actual String with the first captured group i.e, data between `()`.
```

PS : This works with all your current inputs :P

Comment: @TheLostMind-I really appreciate all answers here, but I see this answer simple and working perfect in my case. If you can give a short explanation for expression, that will be great.

Comment: @KodS - Ediyed the answer to give explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

```
          15 EXTR-SITE                                 PIC X.
        05 EXTR-DBA                                    PIC X.
TE0305*     05 EXTR-BRANCH                         PIC X(05).
TE0305*     05 EXTR-NUMBER                         PIC X(06).
TE0305      05 FILLER                                  PIC X(11).
CW0104        10 EXTR-TEXT6                       PIC X(67).
CW0104        10 EXTR-TEXT7                       PIC X(67).
CW0104*     05 FILLER                                  PIC X(567).
```

I think you need to find out more about COBOL before you approach this task.

Columns 1-6 can contain a sequence number, can be blank, or can contain anything. If you are attempting to parse COBOL code you need to ignore columns 1-6.

Column 7 is called the Indicator area. It may be blank, or contain an `*` which indicates a comment, or a `-`, which indicates the line is a continuation of the previous non-blank/non-comment line, or contain a `D` which indicates it is a debugging line.

Columns 73-80 may contain another sequence number, or blank, or anything, and must be ignored.

If your COBOL source was "free format", things would be a bit different, but it is not.

There is no sense in extracting data from comment lines, so your expected output is not valid. It is also unclear where you get the line of dashes in your expected output.

If you are trying to parse COBOL source, you must have valid COBOL source. This is not valid:

```
TE0305      05 FILLER                                  PIC X(11).
CW0104        10 EXTR-TEXT6                       PIC X(67).
CW0104        10 EXTR-TEXT7                       PIC X(67).
```

A level-number (the 05) is a group-item if it is followed by higher level-numbers (the two 10s). A group-item *cannot* have a PICture.

PIC itself can also be written in full, as PICTURE.

PIC can quite easily appear in an identifier/data-name (EPIC-CODE). As could PICTURE, in theory.

PIC and PICTURE could appear in a comment line, even if not a commented line of code.

The method you want to use to find the "description" (which is the identifier, or data-name) is flawed.

```
   01  the-record.
       05  fixed-part-of-record.
           10  an-individual-item PIC X.
           10  another-item COMP-1.
           10  and-another COMP-3 PIC 9(3).
           10  PIC X.
       05  variable-part-of-record.
           10  entry-name OCCURS 10 TIMES.
               15  entry-name-client-first-name
                                  PIC X(30).
               15  entry-name-client-surname
                                  PIC X(30).
```

That is just a short example, not to be considered all-encompassing.

From that, your method would retrieve

```
an-individual-item
COMP-3
and two lines of "whatever happens when PIC is the first thing on line"
```

To save this becoming a chameleon question, you need to ask a new question (or sort it out yourself) with a different method.

Depending on the source of the COBOL source, there are better ways to deal with this. If the source is an IBM Mainframe COBOL, then the source for your source should either be a compile listing or the SYSADATA from the compile.

From either of those, you'd pick up the identifier/data-name at a specific location under a specific condition. No parsing to do at all.

If you cannot get that, then I'd suggest you look for the level-number, and find the first thing after that. You will still have some work to do.

Level-numbers can be one or two digits, in the range 1-49, plus 66, 77, 88. Some compilers also have 78. If your extract is only "records" (likely) you won't see 77 or 78. You'll likely not see 66 (only seen it used once) and quite probably will see 88s, which you may or may not want to include in your output (depending on what you need it for).

```
1.
01.
01  FILLER.
01  data-name-name-1.
01  data-name-name-2 PIC X(80).
    5.
    05.
    05  FILLER.
    05  FILLER PIC X.
    05  data-name-name-3.
    05  data-name-name-4 PIC X.
```

The use of a single-digit for a level-number and not spelling FILLER explicitly are fairly "new" (from the 1985 Standard) and it is quite possible you don't have any of those. But you might.

The output from the above should be:

```
FILLER
FILLER
FILLER
data-name-name-1
data-name-name-2
FILLER
FILLER
FILLER
FILLER
data-name-name-3
data-name-name-4
```

I have no idea what you'd want to do with that output. With no context, it doesn't have a lot of meaning.

It is possible that your selected method would work with your actual data (assuming you pickled your sample, and that what you get is valid code).

However, it would still be simpler to say "if the first word on a line is one- or two-digit numeric, if there is a second word, that's what we want, else use FILLER". Noting, of course, the previous comments about what you should ignore.

Unless your source contains 88-levels. Because it would be quite common for a range of values to require a second line, and if the values happen to be numeric, and one or two digits, then that won't work either.

So, identify the source of your source. If it is an IBM Mainframe, attempt to get output from the compile. Then your task is really easy, and 100% accurate.

If you can't get that, then understand your data thoroughly. If you have really simple structures such that your method works, doing it from the level-number will still be easier.

If you need to come back to this, please ask a new question. Otherwise you're hanging out to dry the people who have already spent their time voluntarily answering your existing question.

Comment: @Bill-Thank you for detailed explanation about cobol format. For this particular project the error with PIC or PICTURE comment is out of scope and also the maximum number of copybook format is limited to 20. I ma trying to clarify one from your answer.  "attempt to get output from the compile" you mean from IBM compiler itself? I am not clear that part.

Comment: If the source is a Mainframe, the compiler output listing has formatted output you can use, with the compiler having already done the complex parsing. It is also possible to get the compiler to produce a SYSADATA output file which would again give you easy access to the information you want. If compile listings are stored for programs containing your source data, your task becomes trivial. If not stored, would require some re-compiles, and then needs someone to do it, at some cost. Much better way to go than you trying to write part of a COBOL compiler.

Comment: Just another note.  For GnuCOBOL, a post preprocessor pass is easier to parse. As Bill mentioned, the flexible and complicated COBOL syntax rules dealt with, in context, by the compiler, and not context free regular expressions.  `cobc -E` produces a nicer to parse listing file when using GnuCOBOL.  And while regex matches may never be 100%, post preprocessor files will increase the chances of *less wrong*, considerably.

Comment: I am not an expert in cobol and I got copybook format and VSAM file. I have to integrate MSSQL with IBM to import data that may involve around 20 copybook formats. I see some recomendation here instead of parsing cobol. I am happy to use any other method if it is more stable and efficient code.

Comment: There is also, JRecord, Cobol2j on sourceforge and legstar

Comment: @KodS Get someone on the Mainframe to include the 20 copybooks in a single program (the program does not need to do anything) and compile it with options MAP and XREF(FULL). They should put the compiler listing to disk, and transfer it to you. If you look at the Data Division Map and the Cross-reference of data names you will see something of what the compiler can do for you. Be very wary of any non-character data. There are a number of questions here about taking data from a Mainframe.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not committed to writing a Cobol parser yourself, a couple of options include:

- Use the **Cobol Compiler** to process the Cobol copybook. This will create a listing of the Cobol-Copybook in a format that is easier to parse. I have worked at companies that converted all there **Cobol**-Copybooks to the equivalent easytrieve copybooks automatically by compiling the Cobol-Copybook in a Hello-World type program and processing the output.
- Products like **File-Aid** have a Cobol parsers that produce an easily digested version of the Cobol Copybook.
- The java project [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/) will convert a Cobol-Copybook to **Xml**. The project provides some examples of processing the Xml with Jaxb.

---

To parse a Cobol-Copybook into a Java list of items using **cb2xml** (taken from [Demo2.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/cb2xml/SVN/HEAD/tree/source/cb2xml_examples/src/net/sf/cb2xml/example/Demo2.java#l44)):

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Condition.class, Copybook.class, Item.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Document doc = Cb2Xml2.convertToXMLDOM(
                       new File(Code.getFullName("BitOfEverything.cbl").getFile()),
                       false,
                       Cb2xmlConstants.USE_STANDARD_COLUMNS);
JAXBElement<Copybook> copybook = unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc, Copybook.class);
```

The program [Demo2.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/cb2xml/SVN/HEAD/tree/source/cb2xml_examples/src/net/sf/cb2xml/example/Demo2.java#l44) will then print the contents of a cobol copybook out:

```
List<Item> items = copybook.getValue().getItem();
for (Item item : items) {
    Code.printItem(" ", item);
}
```

And to print a Cobol-Item [Code.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/cb2xml/SVN/HEAD/tree/source/cb2xml_examples/src/net/sf/cb2xml/example/Code.java#l52):

```
public static void printItem(String indent, Item item) {
    char[] nc = new char[Math.max(1, 50 - indent.length()
                                        - item.getName().length())];
    String picture = item.getPicture();
    Arrays.fill(nc, ' ');
    if (picture == null) {
        picture = "";
    }
    System.out.println(indent + item.getLevel() + " " + item.getName() 
              + new String(nc) + item.getPosition()
              + " " + item.getStorageLength() + "\t" + picture);
    List<Item> childItems = item.getItem();
    for (Item child : childItems) {
        printItem(indent + " ", child);
    }
}
```

The output from **Demo2** is like (gives you the level, field name, start, length and picture):

```
   01 CompFields                                     1 5099 
      03 NumA                                        1 25   --,---,---,---,---,--9.99
      03 NumB                                        26 3   9V99
      03 NumC                                        29 3   999
      03 text                                        32 20  x(20)
      03 NumD                                        52 3   VPPP999
      03 NumE                                        55 3   999PPP
      03 float                                       58 4   
      03 double                                      62 8   
      03 filler                                      70 23  
         05 RBI-REPETITIVE-AREA                      70 13  
            10 RBI-REPEAT                            70 13  
               15 RBI-NUMBER-S96SLS                  70 7   S9(06)
               15 RBI-NUMBER-S96DISP                 77 6   S9(06)
         05 SFIELD-SEP                               83 10  S9(7)V99
```

---

Another **cb2xml** example is [DemoCobolJTreeTable.java](https://sourceforge.net/p/cb2xml/SVN/HEAD/tree/source/cb2xml_examples/src/net/sf/cb2xml/example/DemoCobolJTreeTable.java) which displays a **COBOL** copybook in a Tree table:

[image: Cobol-Copybook displayed in a Tree Table]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I was searching for a while to get good cobol parser. I'll try your recommendation. Since I already selected best answer before, I uprooted your answer.

Comment: Are you working on the host ?  Does your shop have File-Aid or similar ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//let 'lines' be an array of all your lines 
//with one complete line as string per element

for(String line : lines){ 
   String[] splitted = line.split(" ");
   for(int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++){
       if(splitted[i].equals("PIC") && i > 0) System.out.println(splitted[i-1]);
   }
}
```

Please note that I didn't test this code yet (but will in a few minutes). However the general approach shold be clear now.

Comment: add this to your `if` statement `&& i > 0)`

Comment: Why don't you use `Arrays.asList(splitted)` and then the `indexOf` method?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin what do you gain?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin because I think this way is a bit easier to understand (imho)

Comment: @TimHallyburton if you use `split()` you have to remove all the empty position in the array created.

Comment: Please, look to my answer...I really don't understand the down-vote :(

Comment: Please note the comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `String.split("\\s+")`. This method splits the original string into an array of Strings (`String[]`). Then, using `Arrays.asList(...)` you can transform your array into a `List`, so you can search for a particular object using `indexOf`.

Here is an extract of a possibile solution:

```
String words = "TE0305*     05 EXTR-BRANCH                         PIC X(05).";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(words.split("\\s+"));
int index = list.indexOf("PIC");
// Prints EXTR-BRANCH
System.out.println(index > 0 ? list.get(index - 1) : ""); // Added a guard
```

In my honest opinion, this code lets Java working for you, and not the opposite. It is concise, readable and then more *maintainable*.